# Athena/Presto - UNNEST MAP to columns

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

Assume i have a table  like this,

table: qa_list

```
    id   |  question_id |  question  | answer    |  
---------+--------------+------------+-------------
    1    |  100         |  question1 | answer    |  
    2    |  101         |  question2 | answer    |  
    3    |  102         |  question3 | answer    |  
    4    |  ... 
    ...  |  ...
```

and a query that gives below result (since I couldn't find a direct way to transpose the table),

table: qa_map

```
   id   |  qa_map
--------+---------
    1   | {question1=answer,question2=answer,question3=answer, ....}
```

Where qa_map is the result of a map_agg of arbitrary number of questions and answers.

Is there a way to UNNEST qa_map to an arbitrary number of columns as shown below?

```
    id   |  Question_1 |  Answer_1 |  Question_2 |  Answer_2 |  Question_3 | ....
---------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
    1    |  question   | answer    |  question   | answer    |  question   | ....
```

AWS Athena/Presto-0.172

Comment: "* to an arbitrary number*" - no. The number (and types) of the columns of statement must be known to the database **before** it starts running the statement.

Comment: Since an inner query can run on qa_list first, should the number and type be already known to outer queries?

Comment: No, the number of columns is determined by the database, when _parsing_ (analyzing) the statement, not when running it.

Comment: Perhaps try to write the purpose of this unnest map, as there may be other ways without the need to unnest..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Athena (Presto) how to transpose map to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62717002/aws-athena-presto-how-to-transpose-map-to-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to write a query that results in different number of columns depending on the data. The columns must be known before query execution starts. The map you have is as close as you are going to get.

If you include your motivation for wanting to do this there may be other ways we can help you achieve your end goal.