# HIVE (Athena) - Separate array of PKs into column with corresponding value from FK table

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a table with column containing array of PKs in another table.

I want to make a query that will take a certain column from the second table and for each of the PKs in the array set that value in a new column.

For example:

Table `survey` has a column `answers` with array value:

```
|  pk | answers
|-----|------------
|  1  |[1,2,3,4]
|-----|------------
```

Table `answers` has a column `text`, and the following rows:

```
|  pk |         text
|-----|--------------------------
|  1  |'This is an answer'
|  2  |'Another answer'
|  3  |'Yet another answer'
|  4  |'Last answer'
|-----|--------------------------
```

I want to make a query that will return the following:

```
|survey_pk|      answer1      |      answer2   |      answer3       |   answer4   |
|---------|-------------------|----------------|--------------------|-------------|
|    1    |'This is an answer'|'Another answer'|'Yet another answer'|'Last answer'|
|---------|-------------------|----------------|--------------------|-------------|
```

(I don't mind writing the new column names manually).

*** UPDATE ***
@Guru Stron wrote a great answer. But now I am not able to add another columns of table `survey` to the output.

```
|  pk | answers  | date_created
+-----+----------+---------------
|  1  |[1,2,3,4] | 2023-02-17...
+-----+----------+---------------
```

And now the output will be:

```
|survey_pk|      answer1      |answer2|...| date_created 
|---------|-------------------|-------|---|--------------
|    1    |'This is an answer'|  ...  |...| 2023-02-17...
|---------|-------------------|-------|---|--------------
```

Is it possible to get the output that way?

Comment: may be this be of help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62717002/aws-athena-presto-how-to-transpose-map-to-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming number of answers is limited to 4 and the array contains answers ids from the second table you can do something like the following:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH survey(pk, answers) AS (
    values (1, array[1,2,3,4])
),
answers(pk, text) as (
    values (1, 'This is an answer'),
    (2, 'Another answer'),
    (3, 'Yet another answer'),
    (4, 'Last answer')
)

-- query
select pk,
    map[1] answer1,
    map[2] answer2,
    map[3] answer3,
    map[4] answer4
from (
    select s.pk, map_agg(t.index, a.text) map
    from survey s
    cross join unnest(s.answers) with ordinality as t(a, index)
    join answers a on t.a = a.pk
    group by s.pk)
;
```

Output

| pk | answer1 | answer2 | answer3 | answer4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | This is an answer | Another answer | Yet another answer | Last answer |

There is no easy pivoting in Athena/Presto/Trino ATM so this is as far as you can go, potentially you can consider just aggregating back to map (as done in subquery before) or array.

Array aggregation can look like this:

```sql
-- query
select s.pk, array_agg(a.text order by t.index) map
from survey s
cross join unnest(s.answers) with ordinality as t(a, index)
join answers a on t.a = a.pk
group by s.pk;
```

With result:

| pk | map |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [This is an answer, Another answer, Yet another answer, Last answer] |

Comment: It works great, but now I am not able to add another columns from table ```survey``` to the query result. Is it possible to do it like in the example I added to my original question?

Comment: @NaftaliShtern it is actually a separate question, but there are multiple approaches here. One is just to use `arbitrary` aggregation function (`arbitrary(date_created) date_created` ) in the subselect and its result ( `date_created` ) in the outer query.